# If I have to raise my leg above the drawer containing Islamic books to get into bed, am I doing kufr?

Tags: sin, shirk, forgiveness, kufr

Assalamualaikum

**Anybody kindly read my question thoroughly and answer it is kufr or not**

One day I was going for sleep. There was a low laying cupboard near the leg position of the bed. It was closed and had Islamic books in it.

As it is very low we have to raise our leg to get into the bed. One day I was sleepy and angry and I had the knowledge of books in my mind but I don't pay attention to that thought.

I was having waswasa all the time and during that time it was intense. I can't eat sleep, smile or talk. At that time there comes the waswasa that it is kufr what I had done.

I thought I was having no problem. Before having these waswasa I used to take up my leg against the cupboard with books in it for the purpose of sleeping as I have no intention of doing kufr.

But now after affecting of waswas, I am not able to sleep in my bed. At that time, I thought it was just mere waswases happening and there is no sin if we raised our leg against the cupboard containing Islamic books for the purpose of getting into bed as we have no intention to commit kufr and disrespect the books

On thinking these are mere waswases happening to me ,  I take up my leg against the cupboard to lay on the bed. But later I got scared and realize that it may be kufr!

**Please answer it is kufr or not**
Please only answer it is kufr or not by reading my situation  no need for detail discription

Comment: Please only tell kufr or not that is enough

Comment: It's obviously not...

Comment: Thank you let allah give you a happy life

Comment: Please do some prior research before asking questions and show it for example by telling us why you think it could be kufr. Kufr is a matter of belief or disbelief.

Comment: Is that kufr please answer I think that as because I raised my leg that has Islamic books I thought it is just waswas and will not be sin if do for getting into bed , but after that only I thought I had even though done to get into bed I had raised my leg against the cupboard please answer is that kufr

Comment: @ medi 1 saif please tell is it kufr please I don't have any other option I think there is no point to live further

Comment: @Zuhrath It is not kufr. It is not even a sin since you have no intention of disrespecting the Quran or any Islamic literature. If you still feel guilty, ask forgiveness from Allah with a sincere heart and have faith that He will forgive you. Allah is Merciful. He forgives even  shirk if one repents before death. Also I invite you to learn more about our beautiful religion as it is not as strict as you feel it is  .. Salaam :)

Answer (score 1):

The realization that it maybe kufr is probably another waswas of the shaytan and this is not kufr nor is it a sin if you had no intention to disrespect anything.

Comment: During the time I dne the act there was certain waswas in my mind like oh I have disrespected the books etc but I didn't care for the waswas and done it

Comment: Thanks for all answers no need for further answers